# Angular 6: If "Cannot match any routes" moved to other component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a route configuration like below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
];
```

Now, if anyone wants to access `xyz` url like http://localhost:4200/xyz then I am getting this error

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'xyz'

But I want to redirect to the login page in the above case.

Any idea how I can achieve that?

Comment: *The ** path in the last route is a wildcard. The router will select this route if the requested URL doesn't match any paths for routes defined earlier in the configuration. This is useful for displaying a "404 - Not Found" page or redirecting to another route.* https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be adding a wildcard route `**` to catch any unexpected/unmatched/unlisted url and add the redirection to `/login`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/login' }
];
```

**NOTE** : The `**` path in the last route is a wildcard. The router will select this route if the requested URL doesn't match any paths for routes defined earlier in the configuration. **Make sure it is the last entry in list of routes!**

Answer (score 3):

Just add a catch-all path

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/login' }
];
```